# CE Cache - Very strange URLs in cache directory?

Tags: cache, ce-cache, spam, cache-folder

So, I tried pointing this out to our SysAdmin, but he says this looks normal and that EE generates these kinds of cache directories.

But I'd like to verify, do these look like normal cache directories created by EE or CE Cache?

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Does this look "normal" for a cache directory, or like a spam attack?

**EDIT/UPDATE:**

These are in the CE Cache directory: system/user/cache/ce_cache/xxxxxx.

My cache settings:

$config['cache_driver'] = 'dummy'; 
$config['cache_driver_backup'] = 'dummy'; 
$config['ce_cache_static_enabled'] = 'no';

Native EE cache is disabled because this site is using the Transcribe module which needs to have native cache disabled and to use CE Cache instead.

Static cache is also disabled.

Comment: Please post the path where those folders are generated. It also would be helpful to know about your settings in CE-Cache (I suppose you have selected "file" as driver?). Also it could be of interest to know which addons you are using (because an addon might produce those caching-files).

Comment: Updated my post with more info :) - I should also have pointed out, I view this directory often, and today was the first time I've seen any of this, they were also all generated today.

Answer (score 0):

As your caching-driver is "dummy" CE Cache will not cache anything (see also [CE Cache documentation](https://docs.causingeffect.com/expressionengine/ce-cache/user-guide/basics.html#dummy_driver)). So the folders you screenshotted are not generated by CE Cache (or have been generated before the driver was set to "dummy").

I don't know about the contents of your site, but folders like "freegift" and "pdffree" don't sound like cached pages. I think CE Cache generates a folder structure that contains template-groups, template-names and page-names (like cache/ce_cache/74b31e/local/templategroup/singleentry/entryname/entryid/pagesingleentry ).

To check what is going on you could enable CE Cache and set the driver to file with e.g.

```
$config['ce_cache_drivers'] = 'file';
$config['ce_cache_off'] = 'no';
```

Then you delete the ce_cache-folder manually and load some pages. You immediately will see what kind of files CE Cache creates.

Comment: Hmmm, CE Cache is definitely cacheing, and has been for probably about 6 months now just fine...  that is not an issue, and these weird directories just appeared today. I have seen the "normal" cached files, what kinds of directories CE Cache typically creates etc, which typically just reflects the pages/URLs on the site.

Answer (score 0):

If EE handles a request and that request is passed off by EE to a template that is configured to be cached by CE Cache then CE Cache will attempt to cache the file that it serves.

So the real question isn't "why is CE Cache caching these requests?", the question is "why have you configured to your site so these requests point to templates that are cacheable?".

I'd recommend you try to reproduce these requests yourself and see if you shouldn't rather be pointing them at a 404 page or redirecting them to a index or landing page.